# Mapping values from a dictionary where a column meets a particular criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, mapping

I have been using a traditional dictionary mapping method to create a new Pandas column, which looks like the following:

```
product_costs = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}

df['costs'] = df['product'].map(product_costs)
```

This has worked until now, however recently the cost of product 'x' has changed - say for example the cost has increased from 1 to 4 from the 1st April.

My 'df' also has a date column, I am trying to figure out how to map the value of 1 where the date column is pre-April and the value of 4 where the date column is post-April.

I could probably do this iteratively with a for loop, i.e:

```
df['costs'] = ''

index = 0

for i in df['product']:

    if i == 'x' and df.loc[index, 'date'] < 2021-04-01:

        df.loc[index, 'costs'] = 1
        index += 1

    elif i == 'x' and df.loc[index, 'date'] >= 2021-04-01:

        df.loc[index, 'costs'] = 4
        index += 1

    elif i == 'y':

    etc. etc.
```

...however this seems pretty long-winded and tedious when I'm sure the same result could be achieved in a much simpler fashion. Can anyone suggest a solution on how to include the 'where date' element into my mapping?

EDIT - SAMPLE DATA BELOW

```
date (dd-mm)        product

01-02                  x

01-02                  y

01-02                  z

01-03                  x

01-03                  y

01-03                  z

01-04                  x

01-04                  y

01-04                  z
```

to become...

```
date (dd-mm)        product        cost

01-02                  x            1

01-02                  y            2

01-02                  z            3

01-03                  x            1

01-03                  y            2

01-03                  z            3

01-04                  x            4

01-04                  y            2

01-04                  z            3
```

Comment: Coudl you please provide sample data?

Comment: Sure, see edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `np.where()`

You can use [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) based on the date condition.

First convert the dates [**`to_datetime()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Assuming your dates are missing the year (`%d-%m`) but that you want the year to be 2021:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m').apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=2021))
```

Then map with [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) conditioned on the date:

```py
costs_pre = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
costs_post = {'x': 4, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}

df['costs'] = np.where(
    df['date'] < '2021-04-01',
    df['product'].map(costs_pre),
    df['product'].map(costs_post))

#         date  product  costs
# 0 2021-02-01        x      1
# 1 2021-02-01        y      2
# 2 2021-02-01        z      3
# 3 2021-03-01        x      1
# 4 2021-03-01        y      2
# 5 2021-03-01        z      3
# 6 2021-04-01        x      4
# 7 2021-04-01        y      2
# 8 2021-04-01        z      3
```

---

#### `np.select()`

If you have multiple conditions, you could nest [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but [**`np.select()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) would be cleaner.

For example if your costs change on 01-03 and then again on 01-04:

```py
costs1 = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
costs2 = {'x': 4, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
costs3 = {'x': 100, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}

conditions = [df['date'] < '2021-03-01', df['date'] < '2021-04-01']
choices = [df['product'].map(costs1), df['product'].map(costs2)]

df['costs'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df['product'].map(costs3))

#         date product  costs
# 0 2021-02-01       x      1
# 1 2021-02-01       y      2
# 2 2021-02-01       z      3
# 3 2021-03-01       x      4
# 4 2021-03-01       y      2
# 5 2021-03-01       z      3
# 6 2021-04-01       x    100
# 7 2021-04-01       y      2
# 8 2021-04-01       z      3
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, thanks for your help. Final question, if product 'x' changes cost again and there are now 3 possible values associated based on the data - would my best approach be to include another np.where within the np.where?

Comment: @SlowlyLearning yep that's one option but another option would be `np.select()`. give me a sec to update

Comment: @SlowlyLearning updated with `np.select()` option

Answer (score 1):

Pandas where can be useful here too. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html